# Can i run maven dependency in aws lambda via python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda

I got a question about python, maven and aws lambda. Basically I am trying to build dependency trees for my repos using the terminal command

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

This command is being ran via python using the os library, i.e.

```
import os
os.system('mvn dependency:tree')
```

Now comes the issue - I need to run this on AWS Lambda.

Being aware that AWS Lambda is serverless and that the layers of each lambda can only be 250mb, 1) is it possible to run terminal commands via lambda without spinning up any sort of server? and 2) maven usually needs to be installed on a system, thus is it possible, or even viable, to run maven on AWS Lambda?

Any input will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to run terminal commands via lambda without spinning up any sort of server?

Yes, you can run terminal commands in a Lambda function.

> maven usually needs to be installed on a system, thus is it possible, or even viable, to run maven on AWS Lambda?

You can create a [custom Lambda container image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) that includes dependencies.

Additional AWS Blog Post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/